# How to process multidimension array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, mapping

I would like to process a multidimensional array.

Here is my array:

```
DefaultName = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
DefaultCode = ["1D", "2D", "3D"]

Name = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
Code = ["11","12", "13"]
```

from those arrays above, each `DefaultName` value belongs to `DefaultCode` value. For example,

```
DefaulCode "1D" belongs to DefaultName "AB" and so on.
```

For Array `Name` and `Code` as well. Each value of `Code` belongs to `Name`.

```
Code "11" belongs to Name "AB" and so on.
```

My problem is when the length of `Code` is different with length of `Name`. This is the case:

```
Name = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
Code = [None ,"12", "13"]
```

The value of `AB` is none. So I need to looking for the `Code` for the `Name` that empty from `DefaultCode` by mapping the `Name`.

In that case, my expectation, `AB` will has `Code` from `DefaultCode` which is `1D` because `1D` DefaultName is the same as Name of the code.

I tried this, but I am stuck in the part to mapping which Name that empty code and how to looking for DefaultCode.

```
if (len(Name)) == (len(Code)):
    print("There is no empty code")
else:
    print("There is empty code")
    # looking for the Name that does not has code

    # after know which name that without code, then looking for the code from Default Code by mapping the Name
```

Anyone can help me please. I really appreciated for the help. Thank you so much. Gbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a dict lookup if the code is empty.

**Ex:**

```
DefaultName = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
DefaultCode = ["1D", "2D", "3D"]

DefaultCode = dict(zip(DefaultName, DefaultCode)) # --> {'AB': '1D', 'BC': '2D', 'CD': '3D'}

Name = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
Code = [" ","12", "13"]

res = {n: c if c.strip() else DefaultCode.get(n, "N/A") for n, c in zip(Name, Code)}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AB': '1D', 'BC': '12', 'CD': '13'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your output is all the list of array `Name` and `Code`. But my expectation, I only need to output the `Name` and `Code` that empty. Could you please help me then. Thank you

Comment: I only need to output the empty code which is this `'AB': '1D'`

Comment: Then use `res = {n: DefaultCode.get(n, "N/A") for n, c in zip(Name, Code) if not c.strip()}`

Comment: sorry. I edit my question. The case that I have like this `Name = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
Code = [None ,"12", "13"]` and it does not work :( any suggestion please

Comment: use `if c is None`

Comment: yeah, I use this `res = {n: DefaultValue.get(n, "N/A") for n, c in zip(Name, Code) if c is None}` then works. Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is pretty much correct, but there is another simpler way to do it. You can Zip the two lists into one list of tuples Ex:

```
Name = ["AB", "BC", "CD"]
Code = ["11","12", "13"]

NewList = zip(Name, Code)

#iterate through list to demonstrate outputs
for i in NewList:
   print(i)
```

The Output of this code would be:

```
('AB', '11')
('BC', '12')
('CD', '13')
```

Where each element in the list is a tuple. The only difference from a list is that you can't make changes to the values in it hence why they are immutable.